# Differentiator Op-Amp Circuit not giving correct output using single power rail

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

Im trying to simulate an differentiator Op-Amp using a single supply and the LM324 opamp. I built the differentiator circuit using a voltage divider and the LM3234 opamp.
The input wave is a Sinusodial wave, but the output wave is a square wave, but its suppose to be a phas shifted amplified sinusodial wave. I can get the amplification, but my output wave is not a sin wave.

**What am I doing wrong, and how can i fix this?**

Here is the Schematic of the circuit:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Heres an example of what the output should be:
(the sin wave is the input, while the square wave is the output wave, but the output should be an out of phase amplified sin wave))
[image]

Comment: How did you arrive at the C1/R1/C2 network values? (C2 is redundant here btw). Experiment with reducing C1 to 0.1 uF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gain is too high, your output is clipping. At 60 Hz, the 1 uF (C1) will dominate and have an impedance of about 2.6k.

You either need to input a smaller signal, or lower the value of R2.

Edit: Or reduce C1 as Brian Drummond suggested.

Comment: Or dramatically increase the supply voltage, though that's not very practical.